# changing the cursor of mouse by js

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

i trying to change the cursor of mouse by using js for MS CRM dynamics 4.0,
when i calling to method by using ajax, i want to display the cursor of mouse as wait:
document.body.style.cursor="wait";
but it's not working... how can i doing it?

Comment: Can you post any of your code? The syntax appears to be correct from the single line you included.

Comment: it some like that: function BaforeCallingAjaxMethod(){document.body.style.cursor="wait"; CallAjaxMethodNow();}

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing works.

Keep in mind that if the `cursor` is set in CSS on any descendants, that will override the cursor setting on `body`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/88272/

Also notice that I stretched the `width` and `height` of the body to `100%`.

---

Here's a possible solution if other elements are overwriting.

Add this to your css:

```
body.isWaiting, body.isWaiting * {
    cursor:wait !important;
}
```

...then do:

```
document.body.className = 'isWaiting';
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/88272/3/

You'll need to test for browser compatibility.

---

**EDIT:**

Since it sounds as though you can't add your own style sheet on the server side, you could instead try to add one via javascript.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/88272/4/

```
   // string representation of stylesheet content
var styles = 'body.isWaiting, body.isWaiting * {cursor:wait !important;}';

   // grab the <head> element
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

   // create a new "style" element, and set up its properties/content
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
sheet.setAttribute('media', 'all');
sheet.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

if(sheet.styleSheet) {
    sheet.styleSheet.cssText = styles;  // For IE
} else {
    sheet.appendChild( document.createTextNode(styles) );
}

   // append the new <style> element to the <head>
head.appendChild( sheet );

   // give the <body> the class when it is needed
document.body.className = 'isWaiting';
```

Comment: no, it's custom entity on ms crm dynamics 4.0, currently  i cannot inject css for it, another  idea?

Comment: @Danny: Would injecting a stylesheet via javascript be an option for you?

Comment: @Danny: [Give this a try.](http://jsfiddle.net/88272/4/) I'll update my answer with the content in a minute.